# Fos user Bundle can't get it work

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I'm newbie with symfony(I'm using the version 3) I'm trying to use the fosUserBundle but I can't get it work , I followed this :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

the error that I get is : MappingException in MappingException.php line 96:
Class 'Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateur' does not exist

I cleared the cache ,searched in the net but I couldn't find a solution for this issue 
thank you for helping me .

I  have added this  in config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
```

[image: and this is my class Utilisateur]

Comment: Does the file `Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateur` exist? Is that path correct?

Comment: Can you post the fos_user configuration from config.yml?
Is the Utilisateur entity the user_class for FOSUserBundle?

Comment: I have edited my post so you can see what I did , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config.yml change:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
```

Also in Utilisateur.php:

```
namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity
```

that is the problem!

Comment: I have created my own bundle (Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle) which contain the entity folder that contain the Utilisateur class.
Am I obliged to put it in the appBundle ?

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry, I had the wrong paths. Notice the forward slash though. Try that please. I edited my post. I looked at your screenshot wrong before.

Comment: now it works , thank you so much I didn't pay attention on the slash